# Systemverilog assertion a signal is true at least 1 occurence during the simulation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I met a problem when trying to write this assertion. I tried to assert the scenario that signal `B` must be true at least 1 occurrence after signal `A` is true.

The assertion I wrote is below:

```
example  : assert property(
       @(posedge clk) disable iff(reset)
       A |-> ##[0:$] B[->1]) else `uvm_error(....)
```

The problem is, if during the simulation signal `B` is never be true after `A` is true, the `uvm_error` is not executed. I expected it to be executed, and the simulation reports the message:

```
example: started at xxxxxxps not finished
```

It seems the assertion is not finished even the simulation reaches the end.

I looked up in google, there is a similar question:
[Assertion to check for the toggle (0->1) of a signal](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/assertion-check-toggle-0-1-signal)

I also tried use `strong()` operation, it did not help as well.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your English says `B` needs to be true at least once after `A` is true, but your assertion is checking for `A` needing to be true at least once after `B` is true (ie the other way round). Which is correct?

Comment: By the way: this `A[->1]` means the same as this `##[0:$] A[->1]`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I have now corrected it. Thanks very much

Comment: Sorry: two more questions: what is happening? what do you want to happen? (I'm sorry - you speak very good English, but not quite good enough for me to be able to understand the answer to these two questions).

Comment: It is my fault, I did not express my question clearly. The signal A and B I wrote was in a wrong order, my bad.

Comment: I think for this, instead of `$`, you need to put a large enough number for cycles.

Comment: @KaranShah In that case, simulation may reports warning says assertion has the potential to consume a large amount of memory. I will increase the simulation time dramatically.

Comment: How did you use strong() exactly? Do you have the line of code?

Comment: @ShuaiyuJiang Yes increasing simulation time is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your solution depends on which simulator you are using. I tried four and got different behaviours on each.

I think your solution is this:

```
  example3  : assert property(
       @(posedge clk) disable iff(reset)
    A |-> s_eventually B)
    else 
      $error("%t - Assertion example3 failed", $time);
```

based on it working on two simulators and my understanding of SVA. On one simulator the `$error` statement in the *action block* actually gets executed and the message "`Assertion example3 failed`" is displayed; in another a generic error message is displayed.

The `s_` stands for "strong". The assertion means that `B` must occur sometime before the end of the simulation.

Here is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question would have been easier to answer had you included something like this.

```
module M;

  bit stop;  bit clk; initial while (!stop) #5 clk = ~clk;

  bit A, B;

  initial begin
    #20 A = 1;
    #10 A = 0;
    // #10 B = 1;
    #10 B = 0;
    #50 stop = 1;
  end

  example1  : assert property(
       @(posedge clk)
    A |-> B[->1]) 
    else 
      $error("%t - Assertion example1 failed", $time);

  example2  : assert property(
       @(posedge clk)
    A |-> eventually [0:7] B)
    else 
      $error("%t - Assertion example2 failed", $time);

  example3  : assert property(
       @(posedge clk)
    A |-> s_eventually B)
    else 
      $error("%t - Assertion example3 failed", $time);

   final
     $display("Finished!");

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2RtF